# Is there any country or town where Latin is spoken daily?

Tags: contemporary-latin, modern-life

It seems no country nowadays has Latin as official language, besides the Vatican. However, it seems [Italian](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-pope-latin-idUSKCN0HV1O220141006) is the *lingua franca* of the Vatican.

Is there any town where Latin is commonly spoken today? Maybe by not all people, but by a "decent" proportion? (like a place where you could visit and speak in Latin to move around, order coffee, etc).

Maybe a town where signs are officially in Latin? I just have found that for a [train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallsend_Metro_station) in England.

If nothing of this exists, is there some ongoing project of creating such community?

PS: I think this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/does-anyone-learn-latin-as-a-native-language).

Comment: I know of some traditional Catholic monasteries that use the traditional Tridentine Mass in Latin. As well as Latin being used in the Mass, their liturgical calendar and rubrics are also in Latin. Many of their signs are also in Latin on their bulletin board. Needless to say they teach Latin not only as a language but many of their theological classes use books  that are in Latin only, regardless if there are vernacular translations available. Latin is such a big part of their lives that it is like living in the Middle Ages when you visit them.

Comment: @KenGraham besides of that, i) the _modern_ Mass is also celebrated in Latin (e.g. sometimes by the Pope when the attendants are international enough) ii) [ATMs in the Vatican](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ATM-in-Latin-language.jpg) are in Latin iii) there are current news sources in Latin, including the Vatican's iv) there are examples of bishops in recent synods delivering their talk in Latin. Even if none of these are what you are looking for, you may also want to know.

Comment: @KenGraham Oh, I see. So you could basically go there, and have a normal chat in Latin. Can you refer me to one of them? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @luchonacho You can visit them anytime. I know one in the US and several in France.

Comment: @luchonacho, you might especially like this story of "The Latin Speakers of West Virginia".  https://eidolon.pub/the-latin-speakers-of-west-virginia-8581835549d3 It's a summer program, not a town, but you can chat in Latin  or have deeper discourse. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

There are many immersive living Latin programs in the United States and Europe.  I am not sure about elsewhere.  These communities of teachers and learners do form places where you can experience Latin as a modern spoken language in the way that seems to interest you.

The annual Living Latin in NYC conference is an example of a weekend gathering with lectures, classes and socializing all done in Latin.  You can even take a class in spoken ancient Greek.

http://www.paideiainstitute.org/living_latin_in_new_york_city

Here's a lecture in Latin *De iucunditate et utilitate Auli Gelii Noctium Atticarum* from that conference to get a sense of what it's like to have Latin in your ear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ku2ApYHb4Ac

In addition to this, there are other organizations promoting similar experiences of speaking Latin as a modern language.  The North American listings for such events and programs can be found at the [North American Institute of Living Latin website](http://latin.org/wordpress/events/list/)  In Europe Luigi Miraglia is well known for his programs at the [Accademia Vivarum Novum](https://vivariumnovum.net/en/summer-school) in Italy, including an international summer school.  Reginald Foster is well known as a major influence of many of these experts.  He teaches [a summer program](http://thelatinlanguage.org/aestiva-mmxiv/) in Milwaukee.

Perhaps, others will add to my answer with knowledge of these communities of Latin speakers who gather in various ways and times to learn and experience the Latin language in this deep and lively way.